# Python - Get a number from a string containing letters, numbers and symbols

Tags: python, regex, string, split, filtering

I want to get a number from a string, the parts of the number are separated with commas and there are some other symbols too, the number ranges from 1 to 100 million so the number of commas will vary. here's an example:

Input

```
Balance added **⏣ 5,358**: 127%\n**User Balance**: ⏣ 9,951,203'}
```

Output:

```
9951203
```

I need the number after `**User Balance**:`, ignoring all numbers before it.

I've tried making a regex myself but i cant seem to get the number after `**User Balance**:` without also including the words in the string, plus i cant figure out how to deal with the commas, its disheartening to me that ive spent hours on this yet others could do it in a minute, so here i am intending to ask those others :D

Hope i've provided enough information to help you to help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: Split by user balance, Loop for each char, try to cast to int/except means it's not a number.

Comment: If you have a regex you tried, post it and explain what does not work. Else, it is just a mere string splitting/replacing code request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
log = "Balance added **⏣ 5,358**: 127%\n**User Balance**: ⏣ 9,951,203'}"
user_balance = re.search(r"User Balance.*?([\d,]+)", log).group(1).replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand wheter the string information change, so this might be a wrong answer. But I always like to use `.split` or slicing in general in such problems. Like:

```py
my_string = "Balance added **⏣ 5,358**: 127%\n**User Balance**: ⏣ 9,951,203'}"
my_string.split("User Balance**: ⏣")[-1]
```

This would get you

```
9,951,203'}
```

Then, like lucians wrote in his comment, you could try to find integers with try/except or else and combine then.

Comment: This would return `9,951,203'}` .

Comment: Yes, I never stated it was the full solution. But I said, now one can use further modification with try/excrept etc. to find the integer parts. Or use ```.replace``` as the other solutions suggest. Nevertheless I added the output to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int(string.split("User Balance**: ⏣")[1].replace("\'}","").replace(",",""))
```

Output

```
9951203
```

Comment: If you do it this way, you wouldn't need the first `replace()`.
`int(string.split("User Balance**: ⏣ ")[1].replace("\'}","").replace(",",""))`
Also, don't use `string` as a variable name.