# How to extract only numbers from a python generated hash

Tags: python, mysql, hash

So my idea was to create a hash from dog's info for a database.
But after trying to input the hash into the DB it didn't work because of data types incompatibility. So I wanted to get only numbers and drop all the letters from a hash, if possible.

```
import hashlib
DogName = 'Dog'
DogID = '1'
Hash1 = DogName + DogID
Hash2 = Hash1.encode('utf-8')
out = hashlib.sha1(Hash2).hexdigest()
print(out)
```

And I get a hash `9ef8ed01647767afb5e0c4c45b4c373e73f795c1`

So is this possible to get numbers only?

I found something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527283/python-get-a-number-from-a-string-containing-letters-numbers-and-symbols), but this didn't work for me.

Comment: If you want to store hexadecimal hashes, you can't use a numeric column. You will need to use a `varchar` column, for example.

Comment: What's the point? if you remove all the letters you will modify it to an unusable number. Change the column data type in the DB instead.

Comment: So what *did* you do that didn't work?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Comment: Tried a few code examples of a slight similar problem? but that didn't work
like this ----

a_string = "3967604bc659d537cb6966bb1404edf85ad42d5"

numbers = []

for word in a_string.split():

   if word.isdigit():

      numbers.append(int(word))

print(numbers)

}

Also tried to change data type in MySQL, but after changing in EER db in won't let it use this data type directly while editing the db (so it remains CHAR() but changes to INT in connected DB being edited)

So it may be way easier to noy use hashes i guess. Will try to generate smth. 
Thank you.

Comment: By removing the letters, you are likely to get more duplicates, and have no way to decode the digits.  Do you want the hex to be converted to decimal?  How long might the hex be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (
>     hash CHAR(40), 
>     digits_from_hash VARCHAR(40) AS (REGEXP_REPLACE(hash, '[^0-9]', ''))
> );
> INSERT INTO test (hash) VALUES ('9ef8ed01647767afb5e0c4c45b4c373e73f795c1');
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | hash | digits_from_hash |
> | --- | --- |
> | 9ef8ed01647767afb5e0c4c45b4c373e73f795c1 | 9801647767504454373737951 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87ea33a141e5eae667ab129b3d2706c3)*